# How to pass video file from S3 bucket to opencv VideoCapture?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working on an aws lambda function on python that reads videos uploaded to an s3 bucket and extracts a few frames from it, i already have the script for extracting the frames with opencv but i don't know what parameter i should pass to cv2.VideoCapture since the file is only accessible through the s3 bucket.

I've tried passing the video as an s3 object with s3.get_object() as well as with s3.download_fileobj, none of this seemed to work tho.

I've also tried passing just the key of the video file in s3 but it didn't work either (I didn't expect this to work, but i was hopeless).

Code i have now:

```py
import boto3
import cv2
import io

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   s3 = boto3.client("s3")
   bucket_name = "my_bucket"
   video_key = "videos/video.mp4"
   vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=video_path))
   success,image = vidcap.read()
```

I've also tried with:

```py
   vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(s3.download_fileobj(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=video_key, Fileobj=io.BytesIO())
```

But with no luck either

I'm getting success = False and image=None. I expect the output of success to be True and the image to be a numpy array to be able to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV is expecting to access a file on the local disk.

You would need to **download the file from Amazon S3**, then reference that file.

Please note that AWS Lambda only provides 500MB of disk space, and only in the `/tmp/` directory.

Comment: While OpenCV's VideoCapture will download a link (e.g. cv2.VideoCapture('https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4')) I can't get it to download when called from an AWS server.

Comment: I think you should remove or edit this answer: OpenCV is perfectly capable of capturing from remote sources -- as Jay's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 12):

A [presigned url](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url) for S3 object can be used.

```
url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url( ClientMethod='get_object', Params={ 'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key } )

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me from inside of an AWS Sagemaker notebook as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a AWS CloudFront distribution for s3 bucket. Here is the tutorial link: [Use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests S3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/)